# JavaFX Add Node to ScrollPane with SceneBuilder

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

> The problem

In code it works perfectly if i do it like:

```
TilePane tilePane = new TilePane();
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(tilePane);
```

I mean that every time the `TilePane` has more items that can be shown then a `scroll` appears `vertically` or `horizontally` without adding any extra code or setting minimum or preferred size of `TilePane`.

> Using SceneBuilder

Instead of using pure code i want to have the same result as the above using SceneBuilder but every time i am trying to do it something like this: happens[image]

I have to set the preffered size to the `TilePane`.Why thought? And it doesn't work as expected.I want it to automatically work as described in the first lines of the question.A good description is needed...

Comment: Doesn't it work if you just set the `prefWidth` and `prefHeight` back to the default values of `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`?

Comment: @James_D Omg now it works. +1.I was looking that with USE_COMPUTED_SIZE has no width and height into the SceneBuilder so i though it was wrong,but it works.BTW how to format some text in the comments to look like code? Thanks James..

Comment: For formatting code in SO posts see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks. You can use "inline code formatting" (using backticks `\`<code>\``) in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `prefWidth` and `prefHeight` to `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`. These are the default values for a `TilePane`, but SceneBuilder seems to set them to default numeric values when you drop the `TilePane` into a `ScrollPane`.

You can select these values directly by clicking on the drop-down boxes next to the text field for the `prefWidth` and `prefHeight` text fields.