# JavaFx scroll bar with multiple images

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder

I have several images that need to be displayed at the same time using scenebuilder. I wanted to use a scrollbar or scroll pane to allow me to see multiple images at once. However, I can't get the scroll bar to even appear. Am I using scroll pane right?

Here is a picture of scene builder: [image]

Here is the window running: [image]

See how the last flag is cut off? I need to scroll down.

In my code, when I try adding the flowpane with all the images to a scrollpane, I get errors and no scroll bar.

```
public class SampleController {
    
    @FXML private ListView<String> list1;
    
    private ImageView[] imageViews1 = {new ImageView("file:/C:/Users/Pictures/US.png"),
            new ImageView("file:/C:/Users/Pictures/china.png"),
            new ImageView("file:/C:/Users/Pictures/pakistan.png"),
            new ImageView("file:/C:/Users/Pictures/italy.png"),
            new ImageView("file:/C:/Users/Pictures/newzealand.png"),
            new ImageView("file:/C:/Users/Pictures/hungary.png"),
            new ImageView("file:/C:/Users/Pictures/russia.png"),
            new ImageView("file:/C:/Users/Pictures/mexico.png"),
            new ImageView("file:/C:/Users/Pictures/cambodia.png")};
    
    @FXML private ImageView displayWin;
    @FXML private FlowPane imagePane = new FlowPane();
    @FXML private ScrollPane flagScroll;
    
public void initialize()
{
    
    ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList("United States of America", "China", "Pakistan", "Italy", "New Zealand", "Hungary", 
              "Russia", "Mexico", "Cambodia");
    list1.setItems(data);
    list1.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    
    
    
    list1.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>()
            {
                
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue)
                {
                    imagePane.getChildren().clear();
                    for(Integer i : list1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices()) {
                        imagePane.getChildren().add(imageViews1[i]);
                    }
                }           
            });
    

}
}
```

I found this thread but it did not help [JavaFX Add Node to ScrollPane with SceneBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605571/javafx-add-node-to-scrollpane-with-scenebuilder)
I tried to do what this video said also to no avail https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqg3HW73aws&t=259s.

******EDIT********
I need to use a scroll bar control. Scrollpane or listview won't do

Comment: Have you tired using `ListView`?

Comment: Would that work for images? I'd prefer to stick with image views if possible

Comment: Look into `ListView` and `setCellFactory`.

Comment: I tested your code and the ScrollPane works perfectly. Try adding ScrollBarPolicy in AS_NEEDED as follows: 
`flagScroll.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
 flagScroll.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);  `

Comment: Tested it how? You added the scroll pane back in?

Comment: you __must not__ instantiate fields that are injected (as you do with flowpane). Anyway: [mcve] required. _I need to use a scroll bar control._ why? homework?

Comment: @kleopatra yes homework. You are saying I should not instantiate the flowpane itself?

Comment: exactly :) Re-read your coursebook, in particular the chapter about fxml injection

Comment: My book has nothing about fxml in it. Prof said here is a video of what I want done, use scene builder to do it. I think I found a way that needs a bit more tweaking to get perfect but I’ll try and post it later tomorrow when I’m not typing on my phone.